# How do I change background-color of 2 divs when I press 1 other div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, click

How do I make 2 divs (header and sub-header) change color when div (change) is pressed?

The sub-header is going to be changed to another color, not the same color as header.

```
<div class="change">
  Click this to change the background-color of the 2 headers.
</div>

<div class="header>
  Header
</div>

<div class="sub-header">
sub-header
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could approach it like this...

Create a new class for each new background color you'd like:

```
.header {
  background: grey;
}

.header-alt {
  background: lightblue;
}

.sub-header {
  background: lightblue;
}

.sub-header-alt {
  background: grey;
}
```

Then use jQuery [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to add/remove those classes on click of the div `change`

```
$(".change").click(function() {
  $('.header').toggleClass("header-alt");
  $('.sub-header').toggleClass("sub-header-alt");
});
```

**Example**

```js
$(".change").click(function() {
  $('.header').toggleClass("header-alt");
  $('.sub-header').toggleClass("sub-header-alt");
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div {
  padding: 20px;
}

.change {
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  background: grey;
}

.header-alt {
  background: lightblue;
}

.sub-header {
  background: lightblue;
}

.sub-header-alt {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change">
  Click this to change the background-color of the 2 headers
</div>

<div class="header">
  Header
</div>

<div class="sub-header">
  sub-header
</div>
```

[Codepen if you prefer...](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/qRLjxY)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that does exactly what you described. This solution is using jquery. Look at the code below and feel free to ask if something is not clear :)

```js
var colorChanged = false;
$('.change').click(function() {
  if(!colorChanged){
      $('.header').css('background-color','red'); 
      $('.sub-header').css('background-color','blue');
      colorChanged = true;
    } else {
      $('.header').css('background-color','transparent'); 
      $('.sub-header').css('background-color','transparent');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change">
  Click this to change the background-color of the 2 headers.
</div>

<div class="header">
  Header
</div>

<div class="sub-header">
sub-header
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to make it so when you click the change button again, the color goes back to "normal"?

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of `div.change` assign background-color to other divs `$('.header').css("background-color","red");`

`$('.change').on('click',function(){
$('.header').css("background-color","red");
$('.sub-header').css("background-color","red");
})`

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/y5tLzbsc/

Comment: is it possible to make it when I click the change button, it toggles back?

Comment: `toggleClass` will do the work, check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y5tLzbsc/2/

Answer (score 0):

you give both of them the class 'active'
and on your css

```
.header.active{
    background:blue;
 }
 .sub-header.active{
    background:red;
 }
```

and on your js:

```
document.querySelector('.change').onclick = function(){
   document.querySelector('.header').className += " active";
   document.querySelector('.sub-header').className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an event listener. See demo:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className.indexOf('change') > -1) {
    var headerEl = document.querySelector(".header");
    var subHeaderEl = document.querySelector(".sub-header");

    // This will toggle the color change on or off after each click
    if (headerEl.className.indexOf('color') > -1) {
      headerEl.className = headerEl.className.replace(" color", "");
      subHeaderEl.className = subHeaderEl.className.replace(" color", "");
    } else {
      headerEl.className += " color";
      subHeaderEl.className += " color";
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.header.color {
  background-color: red;
}
.sub-header.color {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="change">
  Click this to change the background-color of the 2 headers.
</div>

<div class="header">
  Header
</div>

<div class="sub-header">
  sub-header
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with HTML and CSS.  There is no need to use anything advanced or exotic.

The `checkbox` becomes the click input and it is hidden off screen.  Since a connected `label` acts as the `checkbox` it becomes your input button.  The `label` is the replacement for your original top `DIV`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#hidden_checkbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: 0;
}

#visible_label {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#hidden_checkbox:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 50, 0);
}

#hidden_checkbox:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 50);
}

.header {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 128);
}

.sub-header {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 0, 128);
}
```

```html
<input id="hidden_checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label id="visible_label" for="hidden_checkbox">Click this to change the background-color of the 2 headers.</label>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="sub-header">Sub-header</div>
```